# Wordpress: Submitting a post method form on single custom post type page returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm now developing on a Wordpress theme.

I have a custom post type named `activity`:

```
register_post_type($class::$post_type, array(
    'label' => $class::$post_type_name,
    'description' => $class::$post_type_description,
// ....
```

And I'm editing the `single-activity.php` template, I have a form on it:

```
<form id="form_main" method="post" action="">
    <?php wp_nonce_field(); ?>
    <!-- Other fields -->
</form>
```

When I open the url `http://localhost/activity/slug/`, the page goes well.

But when I submit the form, i.e. request the url with a `post` method, it was causing a `404` response, the url is just simply the same.

What could be the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of debugging, I found the reason: the `$_POST` fields affects the query.

In my case, I submit a field with key and values:

```
$_POST['title'] = 'new title';
```

I intend to create a new post with this title.

But in fact, the default query use this field as a `where` condition to filter the current page, and finally got no results.

So, when posting data, **BE AWARE of the reserved field names:**

like:

- s
- p
- title
- page

For more, check about the document.